# French babel package affects indentation in nested lists

Tags: lists, indentation, babel, babel-french

I noticed that adding

```tex
\usepackage[french]{babel}
```

line (into a basic `article` document, for example) affects indentation of nested `enumerate` lists (possibly `itemize` too). The indentation becomes noticeably shorter than before. Using `babel` with English does not have this effect.

Is this related to some French typography rules?

What would be an easy way to restore default indentation of nested lists?

Comment: french has a quite good and extensive documentation which describes what it changes and how to avoid it. You get it for example with `texdoc babel-french`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `\frenchsetup` command. In the following example the lists are reset to the default style:

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\frenchsetup{
   StandardItemizeEnv,
   StandardEnumerateEnv,
   StandardItemLabels,
   StandardListSpacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
 \item One 
 \item two
\begin{enumerate}
 \item One 
 \item two
 \item Three
\end{enumerate}
 \item Three
\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}
 \item One 
 \item two
 \begin{itemize}
  \item One 
  \item two
  \item Three
 \end{itemize}
 \item Three
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]